# How to get all entities in database using hibernate with a critria?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am writing an springBoot application and have 3 classes :

```
@Table(name = "notification")
public class Notification{
  
  @Id
  @Column("notification_id")
  // generateStrategy
  long id;

  @ManyToMany
  List<Role> roles;
  
  @ManyToMany 
  List<User> users;
}
```

another class :

```
public class Role{

\\ id and some other fields.

}
```

the User class is the same. The relation between Notification and Role is unidirectional.(also true for notification and user)

Now, I'm using hibernate to persist data in database.

my question is how can I retrieve all Notification which has a given role ? for example I have an "admin" role(which is an object!) and I want to find all notification that contain "admin" in their "roles" list.

Is it possible to write just by Hibernate Itself ?(I know that hibernate is capable of generating sql code when we write functions names in specific format in our database interface).

if it is not possible, how can I write an efficient SQL query manually?

Comment: "*I know that hibernate is capable of generating sql code when we write functions names in specific format in our database interface*" - Afaik, this is a feature of `spring-data-jpa`, not hibernate itself.

Comment: Are you using `spring-data-jpa`'s `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`? If so, you could try adding `List<Notification> findByRoleId(long roleId);` (not sure if it works, but I vaguely remember doing something like this in the poast).

Comment: I'm using spring-data-jpa but just using Repository interface (not JpaRepository or CrudRepositry). I will try

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to consider there, let's try to breakdown each:

#### Using JPQL

```java
@Query("SELECT n FROM Notification n JOIN n.roles r WHERE r.name = :roleName")
List<Notification> findNotificationsByRoleName(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
```

#### Using Spring Data JPA method naming

```java
List<Notification> findByRolesName(String roleName);
```

#### Using the Criteria API

(more verbose and programmatic approach to construct queries)

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Notification> cq = cb.createQuery(Notification.class);
Root<Notification> notificationRoot = cq.from(Notification.class);
Join<Notification, Role> roleJoin = notificationRoot.join("roles");

Predicate roleNamePredicate = cb.equal(roleJoin.get("name"), "admin");
cq.where(roleNamePredicate);

TypedQuery<Notification> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
List<Notification> notifications = query.getResultList();
```

Basically, you may choose any. If you prefer a bit more declarative approach and simplicity, then the first two methods are recommended. If you need a dynamic and programmatic approach, then the Criteria API would be the choice

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Role entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    private String role;

\\ id and some other fields.

}
```

To fetch all notifications that contain a specific role in their roles list you just need to define a method in the JpaRepository like this:

```
public interface NotificationRepository extends JpaRepository<Notification, Long> {
    List<Notification> findByRolesRole(String role);
}
```

And call the method in your service like this:

```
@Autowired
NotificationRepository notificationRepository;

List<Notification> adminNotifications = notificationRepository.findByRolesRole("admin");
```

Comment: Everytime you post an answer I learn something new :). Didn't know that I can chain `where` this way in JPA, many thanks for your always handsome tips.